# django_auth_ldap no module named ldap

Tags: django, ldap

I am trying to get the django_auth_module working but I don't think I managed to install it properly.

I downloaded the package and ran setup.py install.
Then in my settings.py file I tried to import the module ldap and it gave me the following error :

```
ImportError: no module named ldap
```

I am working on a CentOS 6 server.

Maybe it has to do with where I should install the module? The folder is in the directory just above my site folder, but maybe that's wrong...

RESOLVED :
Ok, I just needed to install the module python-ldap... problem solved!

Comment: You should write your solution as an answer and mark it as correct so that this is no longer an Unanswered Question.

Comment: on installing this give error :P     "command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Comment: Installing python-ldap on Windows is a humongrous task :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Install missing module

Hint: To install python-ldap with pip on Ubuntu, some libraries are needed.
Use the `apt-get` commands to install them.

Python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip install python-ldap
```

Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip3 install pyldap
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Still not able to get this installed for Windows 8.1 Enterprise, Python3.5. After trying to install python-ldap via pip I now get a issue with the ssl certificates, so I'm wondering how else I can install this without using pip install.

Comment: No SO answer for this problem solved it. I'm using the "new" Ubuntu 18.04. Installed already all imaginable packages...

Comment: it is my impression that the 2 vs 3 is no longer relevant, pyldap is merged into python-ldap from https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=pyldap#usage Does it work with Python 3?

A0: Yes, from 3.0 on.

A1. For earlier versions, there’s pyldap, an independent fork now merged into python-ldap.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command to install for Python3.

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip3 install pyldap
```