# Missing module django_auth_ldap?

Tags: python, django, ldap

So all the tutorials on ldap with Django start by saying

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch
```

but no matter what I'm getting an error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'reportgenerator.settings' (Is it on sys.path?
Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 
django_auth_ldap.config
```

Am I missing something? I have python-ldap installed.

This question was solved by running the following on the command line:

```
pip install django-auth-ldap
```

Comment: pip install django-auth-ldap

Comment: possible duplicate of [django\_auth\_ldap no module named ldap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857680/django-auth-ldap-no-module-named-ldap)